# Update css of an asp.net datagrid in jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, css, datagrid

I am trying to update the css of a datagrid cell when the user clicks on it. I can get it to enter a javascript function on click of the cell, but I can't get it to update the css. I am very new to .NET, and so I might be doing this all wrong, just let me know if there is a better way. Here is what I am trying:

```
function UpdateRole(roleOrEmail, roleID, rowNum, employeeID) {
alert("updating role..." + rowNum + " " + roleID + " " + employeeID + " " + roleOrEmail);
var loadImage = 'url(http://localhost:4353/BrokerBuy/Images/flatbarberpole.gif)';
$("#MainContent_userRoles_GridView1 tr").each(function () {
    //Skip first(header) row
    if (this.rowIndex == rowNum) {
        $(this).find("tr:last").css('background-image', loadImage);
    }
});}
```

I tried find("tr").eq(rowNum).find("td").eq(1) as well.

Here is the markup:

```
<td style="width:50%;" onclick="UpdateRole('role','Buyer','0','1091912');" class="statusOff">Inactive</td>
```

I can't reference it via the class, though, because several rows have that class, and I only want to update the row that was clicked. The 0 in the updateRole function is the index of the row. This is passed to my function as "rowNum" I was hoping to be able to use that index as a means of accessing the correct row/data item.

Comment: Is your problem that the css class is not applied to the correct item? Could please show the markup? Inspecting your markup in Chrome or FireBug could help you get the correct item.

Comment: No, the problem is that I can't seem to grab the right cell in jquery. If I just set it to update the css for "this", it works fine, and the css is changed to a loading bar... it's just not in the right spot.

Comment: Could you please show your markup? Otherwise we'll never know how to select the right cell.

Comment: Ok, I added the markup to my post.

Comment: Ok, I got it... Sorry, I just added an ID to the cell on the onclick event. Then just referenced it from there. Thank you very much for your help, though!

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to select "tr:last" in your jquery find.  I think you are trying to find the td instead, as you already have the row aka $(this). I pasted your code into a project, changed it to  $(this).find("td:last"), and changed the background color of the cell and it worked fine for me.